# T-SQL truncate time (not round) to the nearest minute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Looking for the most efficient and elegant way to do truncate the time to the minute

```
-- I need to truncate the time to the minute, 
-- this code almost works but rounds up 
SELECT
    CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS datetime2(7)) AS EventDatetime2,
    CAST(CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS datetime2(7)) AS TIME(0)) AS EventTime
```

Comment: Are you receiving the datetime as an actual string literal?

Comment: no this is for demo purposes to show the unwanted rounding behavior of the cast operator

Answer (score 5):

As Larnu posted, if you want to round up or down depending on the seconds value, a simple convert to smalldatetime will do.

If you want to truncate, there are several ways, the simplest is probably just to add minutes to midnight (only posting because I prefer without the magic dates like 1900-01-01):

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2(7) = '2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333';
DECLARE @d  datetime2(7) = CONVERT(date, @dt);

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @d, @dt), @d);
```

Another way is more intuitive but a little ugly:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2(7) = '2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333';

SELECT SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS
(
  DATEPART(YEAR,   @dt), 
  DATEPART(MONTH,  @dt), 
  DATEPART(DAY,    @dt), 
  DATEPART(HOUR,   @dt), 
  DATEPART(MINUTE, @dt)
);
```

Comment: Definitely need to truncate and it needs to be fast ill do some testing and see the dateadd seems to be the way to go...  I feel like the cast to tiime(0) is a bug or at the best inconsistent with how as cast to date would work?

Comment: @JasonHorner The `(0)` in `time(0)` indicates how many decimal places to keep *after* the seconds, but cast/convert rounds everything else before it takes it away. Try with `time(1)` from `15:15:30.9511111`, same thing, it doesn't discard the 5, it uses it to round first.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess my point is that rounding is unexpected and undesirable from a cast

Comment: @JasonHorner Well, you could also expect and desire your car to fly, but if it doesn't, that's not a bug. :-) Complex built-in functions have to work one way or the other by default, there's no way to satisfy the expectations of every user simultaneously. I do concede, though, that I would have expected `SELECT CONVERT(int, 3.7);` to round up, not down. For numerics at least we have `ROUND()`, `FLOOR()`, `CEILING()`, etc.

Comment: yes, but I'm casting not rounding... I'm ok with losing precision not changing the value (one could argue these are effectively the same). still trying to find the wings on my car get strange looks in the parking lot at Tim Horton's :)

Comment: Well, what happens with `SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, '23:59:59.997');`? With some conversions casting and rounding are intentionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "round" to the nearest minute you could just `CONVERT` the value to a `smalldatetime`; they are only accurate to 1 minute:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime,CONVERT(datetime2,'2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333'));
```

If you want to, you can then `CONVERT` back to your original data type.

If you want to truncate (so strip the minutes) you could use the old `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` method:

```sql
DECLARE @DateTime2 datetime2(7) = '2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333';
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'19000101',@DateTime2),CONVERT(datetime2(7),'19000101'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using `left()` and the implicit conversion.

Depending on the actual USE CASE, the outer `convert()` is optional

**Example**

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2(7) = '2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333';

select convert(smalldatetime,left(@dt,16))
```

**Results**

```
2021-09-02 15:15:00
```

Comment: I considered this but assumed perhaps incorrectly that the string manipulation would negatively impact performance its worth testing as its an obvious solution... wish there was was a  built-in truncate function that worked with dates and numerics

Comment: @JasonHorner  At a minimum, it is 1 function call.   "One test is worth a thousand expert opionions"  :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the `DATEADD` and `CAST(... AS SMALLDATETIME)` approaches effectively gives you a minute "floor", like so:

```
SELECT CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS DATETIME2(7))                  AS EventDatetime2,
       CAST(CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS DATETIME2(7)) AS TIME(0)) AS EventTime,
       CAST(CAST(DATEADD(
                SECOND,
                (DATEPART(SECOND, CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS DATETIME2(7))) * -1),
                CAST('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333' AS DATETIME2(7))) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS TIME(0));
```

| EventDatetime2 | EventTime | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-02 15:15:30.9233333 | 15:15:31 | 15:15:00 |

The `DATEADD` in this example subtracts the number of seconds from the datetime before converting it to a smalldatetime, so when that cast/convert does its rounding it will always go to the lower minute.

If, however, your input value is the sort of string literal that the wording of your question implies, you could also do this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333', CHARINDEX('T', '2021-09-02T15:15:30.9233333')+1, 6) + '00' AS TIME(0));
```

and get this result:

```
15:15:00
```

Comment: thanks, I'll look at the approach, the end result should be a time(0) data type per the code I shared just truncated or down to the nearest minute. the rounding up to the closest minute is what is causing the issue.